# Using Georeference information stored in tfwx (from ArcGIS) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff

I have georeferenced some images (ArcGIS -> Update Georeferencing) which creates a *.tfwx file with the new parameters for georeferencing.

I renamed it to *.tfw but QGIS is not able to read the georeferencing information.

Does anybody has any useful tips how to fix this?

Comment: It happens the same to me no tifw or tfwx is useful

Answer (score 6):

tfw and tfwx are not the same. The information in `aux.xml` gets lost.

See these links:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/48357-tfw-v.s.-tfwx

http://walt.therices.org/index.php/2009/09/georeferencing-dpi-quirks/

As a workaround, `rectification` in Arcgis should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this and you might try a couple of things.  (I contemplated reporting this to ESRI at one point but apparently I haven't.  You might search the ESRI Forums via Google for help too; it seems the issue of georeferenced tifs not displaying properly in ArcGIS or other programs is a recurring issue.)

First, check the world file.  In one case I found the rotation values to be in exponential notation.  I don't know if QGIS can read world files with such values but they were so small I was willing to live with 0 values.

Second, there may be a conflict between the world file and header information.  Make a copy of your tif with an image program like the free Irfanview.  Make a copy of your world file and rename it to match the copied tif (except for the tfw extension of course) and see if that works.  Clumsy but I've had some success with it.