# How to merge a 4 band tfwx file into one tif for use in Qgis

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, georeferencing

I have a tfwx file and when I open it in arcmap it is displayed as 4 bands. 
I would like to use the georeferenced file in qgis since I know nothing about arcmap.

Comment: Perhaps the following posts might help: [Georeference information stored in tfwx (from ArcGIS). Is it possible to see the georeference in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42988/georeference-information-stored-in-tfwx-from-arcgis-is-it-possible-to-see-the) and [Georeferenced TIF files, can TFW files be created from TFWX files? - (ArcGIS 9.3)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87101/georeferenced-tif-files-can-tfw-files-be-created-from-tfwx-files-arcgis-9-3).